# Granite counter tops with granite backsplash in kitchen: need to replace caulk

Tags: kitchens, replacement, caulk, granite

New construction, 7 years old. We have quartz "granite" counter tops with an approximate 6 inch bit as a backsplash. The caulk has degraded and I need to remove it, make sure the moisture from the sink isn't causing an issue, and then reseal it.

In some places the gap is (in my view) pretty wide while the two surfaces are flush in other places.

For best results should I shim the counter to lift it in the low places? Or just fill it all with clear silicone?

Comment: Depending what pretty wide is caulking alone and/or with backer rods for fill.  Granite does not bend, so unless in sections and some sections are low compare to the rest, then I would leave it be.

Comment: Rather than *clear* silicone, use a *tinted* caulk to match the surround.